# Angular 2, другой URL в адресной строке

Tags: url, angular2

Как сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке отображался один URL, а в base URL, указать другой для angular 2 приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Есть способ, который я нашел, читая доку.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Этот путь будет виден в адресной строке как основной

```
/my/app
```

можно пойти дальше. Сделать мета тег и считать его в программе

```
export const MAIN_URL = (<HTMLTemplateElement>document.head.querySelector('[name="main-url"]')).content;
```